# AnyStock - can an annotation be represented in the chart scroller?

Tags: anychart

I would like to show the location of vertical annotations in the stock chart scroller so that when the user zooms/pans away from the annotation, they are still aware of its location on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library 8.7.0 doesn't support annotations and markers in the stock scroller. It can show a series thumbnail only.